# Liquibase is not working after upgrading spring boot from 2.0.5.RELEASE to 2.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

Liquibase is not working after upgrading spring boot to 2.3.1.RELEASE which leads to getting the following error (While starting the spring boot application):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use default schema name my-schema on Microsoft SQL Server because the login schema of the current user (dbo) is different and MSSQL does not support setting the default schema per session.
```

Base on the error it looks like permission issue; I even tried with user having permission on the particular schema my-schema and then tried again but now the logs says:

```
2020-07-28 14:42:50,759 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:50,915 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: SELECT TOP 1 MD5SUM FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL
2020-07-28 14:42:51,068 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:51,221 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET MD5SUM = NULL
2020-07-28 14:42:51,537 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:51,690 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:51,838 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOG
2020-07-28 14:42:51,987 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
2020-07-28 14:42:51,994 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:52,145 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2020-07-28 14:42:53,188 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:53,343 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET MD5SUM = '8:417f9207fe8e8268e383719af6f9d7c7' WHERE ID = '1' AND AUTHOR = 'system' AND FILENAME = 'database/changelog/initial_schema.xml'
2020-07-28 14:42:53,654 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: select schema_name()
2020-07-28 14:42:53,810 INFO  [main] liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger: UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET MD5SUM = '8:30308b26d27500571e3f9bbaf68918de' WHERE ID = '2' AND AUTHOR = 'system' AND FILENAME = 'database/changelog/initial_schema.xml'
```

Liquibase is now trying to update the my-schema.DATABASECHANGELOG MD5SUM column value. It has modified some of the records MD5SUM as NULL  and for some of the field it has set new MD5SUM value; its performing this operation each and every time I am starting the spring boot application.

**One of my finding when we are using:**

```
sprint boot parent version 2.3.1.RELEASE it internally uses
<liquibase.version>3.8.9</liquibase.version>
Previous sprint boot parent version : 2.0.5.RELEASE
<liquibase.version>3.5.5</liquibase.version>
```

I have even tried to to downgrade the liquibase version to:

```
<liquibase.version>3.5.5</liquibase.version>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: This is cross posted in the LB forums, I will try and answer there

Comment: @ronak Thanks for helping, I am sharing the LB forums link: https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibase-is-not-working-after-upgrading-3-5-5-to-3-8-9/4483